# Select Bootstrap button with data attribute on page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got the following jQuery to show / hide Divs based on a `data-filter` attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".filter-button").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    if(value == "all")
    {
        $('.filter').show('1000');
    }
    else
    {
        $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
        $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');
    }
});
```

I've also got this jQuery that sorts the Divs:

```
$('#alpha-button-az').on('click', function() {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a,b){
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $(".profile-container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});

$('#alpha-button-za').on('click', function() {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(b,a){
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $(".profile-container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

Here's the HTML that I use to filter the Divs:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-active-class="location-filter" data-filter="all"><input type="radio" name="options" id="all" autocomplete="off" checked>All</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-active-class="location-filter" data-filter="new"><input type="radio" name="options" id="new" autocomplete="off" checked>Newcastle</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-active-class="location-filter" data-filter="man"><input type="radio" name="options" id="man" autocomplete="off" checked>Manchester</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-active-class="location-filter" data-filter="dub"><input type="radio" name="options" id="dub" autocomplete="off" checked>Dublin</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-active-class="location-filter" data-filter="win"><input type="radio" name="options" id="win" autocomplete="off" checked>Winnersh</label>
    <label class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-active-class="location-filter" data-filter="lon"><input type="radio" name="options" id="lon" autocomplete="off" checked>London</label>
</div>
<br />
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="alpha-button-az" class="btn btn-default" data-active-class="alpha-sort"><input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked>A-Z</label>
    <label id="alpha-button-za" class="btn btn-default" data-active-class="alpha-sort"><input type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" checked>Z-A</label>
</div>
```

What I want to do is be able to select one of each of the buttons on page load.

So far, I've got this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#alpha-button-az").click();
    $(".filter-button").click();
});
```

This works for the A-Z buttons (with A-Z selected on page load) but because the filter is using a custom attribute, I don't know how to select a specific button. At the moment, it's selecting the last button in the group.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "select one of each of the buttons"? As in run it's function?

Comment: I would like one of the buttons to be "clicked" so they show as active. For example: https://snag.gy/y0O7mx.jpg

This is what happens at the moment: https://snag.gy/8puhsw.jpg

Comment: See the answer I've provided. Hopefully that works! I'm not sure what element you're using in Bootstrap that looks like that, I couldn't find it. If you send me the docs reference then I can be of more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first code snippet, slightly changed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".filter-button").click(function(){
    var value = this.dataset.filter; // Note this code change btw!

    if(value == "all")
    {
        $('.filter').show('1000');
    }
    else
    {
        $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
        $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');
    }
});
```

and the second:

```
function sortAlphaAscending() {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a,b){
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $(".profile-container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
}

function sortAlphaDescending() {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(b,a){
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $(".profile-container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
}

$('#alpha-button-az').click(sortAlphaAscending);
$('#alpha-button-za').click(sortAlphaDescending);
```

Now, instead of "calling" the event handler, just call the function you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Do functions here to data
    sortAlphaAscending();

    // Activate elements here
    $(".selector").attr("active");
});
```

DISCLAIMER: I'm 99% sure you want to add the `active` attribute, but I haven't tested that.

**EDIT**: This updated HTML could work. Please add the `active` property to each element you want to begin being the active element. I can't see your HTML for the buttons in your question, so as an example:

```
<button id="some-button">...</button>
```

would become

```
<button id="some-button" active>...</button>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, all the buttons work OK, but I don't think I explained myself very well with what I want... :)

At the moment, when the page loads, all divs are visible and unsorted. They can then select a button for "location" to filter the divs. They can also click a button to sort alphabetically.

What I would like, is for one of the "location" buttons to be selected and the divs filtered automatically. I also want the sort to happen on page load.

Comment: @Kungfauxn00b No worries! What is it that you need?

Comment: Using the last bit of your code to call the function does sort the divs but the "A-Z" button doesn't show as active.

Also, I want the "All" locations button to show as active.

Comment: @Kungfauxn00b Did you change the `$(".selector")` to the selector for your element? Try doing that, and copying that line of code for each element you want active. Or, edit your HTML, I'll edit my answer to show you that.